# Can't find Attached Attributes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm new in WPF, but not in programming, I'm trying to find Attached Properties like ZIndex, Canvas.Top, Canvas.Left but it doesn't show me in C# code.

- I know that I have to put my Control in Canvas
- I know there is another method which calls Canvas.SetIndex  (which I also couldn't find)

I can see all those properties in my XAML code, but cant reach them with my C# Code

```
 <Button Canvas.Left="192" Canvas.Top="102" Content="Button" Height="108" Name="button1" Width="173" /> <- XAML Part

  button1.Canvas.Top = 5; <- C# Part
```

it says button1 doesn't have any Canvas.Top method or Attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Button` itself doesn't have a `Canvas`. This should do it:

`Canvas.SetTop(button1, 5);`

and then:

`canvas.Children.Add(button1);`

Comment: thanks man , i didnt know that the method SetTop is coming from class Canvas , i ve tried only canvas1.SetTop :D

Comment: @Guardian no problem man, if the answer helped you and it was what you were looking for, make sure to mark my answer as correct. Also for future questions you should always mark an answer as correct, if there is one.

Comment: yeah, ik , but i have to wait for it :D

Answer (score 0):

c# equivalent of xaml `Canvas.Top` attribute will be `Canvas.TopProperty`. `Canvas.Top` doesn't exist in c# code; in xaml it is recognized due to attached DP naming conventions.

Canvas.TopProperty can be set to any DependencyObject using `SetValue` method:

```
button1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 5.0);
```

`Canvas.SetTop()` internally uses `SetValue()` with `Canvas.TopProperty`. `Canvas.SetTop()` has an advantage of being type-safe. It accept `double` parameters, not `object`. E.g. `button1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 5);` throws ArgumentException, because `5` is int